# How to convert byte type value to int type value

Tags: go, type-conversion

For the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    str := "0125"
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(str[0]))
    intVar := int(str[0])
    fmt.Println(intVar)
}
```

---

below is the output:

```
uint8
48
```

---

Type conversion is about converting `uint8` type value `0`(`str[0]`) to  `int` type value `0`

Why `uint8` type conversion to `int`, takes UTF-encoding value of `0`(which is `48`)?

Comment: You are not formatting it right. Try fmt.Printf("%T, %c",...). %d prints decimal value.

Comment: `"0"` and `0` are not the same thing.

Comment: @Marc yes `48` is the encoding value of `"0"`. Is type conversion not converting `"0"` to `0`? Do I need to use `strconv.Atoi()`? Query edited with code modification

Comment: No, of course not. This would be parsing, not type conversion.

Comment: @overexchange according to your logic how would you map 'a'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following approach

**For Example**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    str := []byte("0125")
    aByteToInt, _ := strconv.Atoi(string(str))
    fmt.Println(aByteToInt)
}
```

You can run following code here https://play.golang.org/p/iq8Q9PkhM43

Answer (score 1):

The ASCII value of 0 is 48 that is why you are getting the number 48 in your scenario. This is the expected behavior in go. One more simplest solution is as below,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    str := "0125"
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(str[0]))
    // Subtract ascii value of 0 from your ascii number and you will get integer number
    // Here it will be 48 - 48 = 0
    fmt.Println(int(str[0] - '0'))
    // Here it will be 49 - 48 = 1
    fmt.Println(int(str[1] - '0'))
}
```

If you remove type casting and just use it like `fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(str[0] - '0))` you will get `uint8` with value `0`
Try it in go-playground https://play.golang.org/p/tdbWS-44VLB